# ObservableDictionary event raiser

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

I'm studying some examples provided by Microsoft for win8 development. I opened **BasicControls** sample and noticed `LayoutAwarePage` class and more precisely `ObservableDictionary` class. Reading about [implementing events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [raising them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I can't see who's responsible to raise `MapChangedEventHandler` event. Based on parameters I believe that `private void InvokeMapChanged(CollectionChange change, K key)` method do this. But according to MSDN we need to provide a protected method that begins with **On** which doesn't occur in ObservableDictionary.

So, who raises `MapChangedEventHandler`?

Answer (score 1):

An event in a class can be raised from within the class without need of an additional method to that.

So, if `MapChangedEventHandler` is an event, it can be called from inside the class just by this:

```
if (MapChangedEventHandler != null)
    MapChangedEventHandler( parameters );
```

The only motive I can see (I'm not an expert) to the existance of those `OnWhatever` methods is to allow raising events `from outside` the class, or `from some derived class`, since events can only be raised from inside the declaring class.

Those `OnWhatever` methods must be some `good practice` (not a rule, nor a compiler rule).
Maybe they also take care of some additional stuff together with raising the event.
If they are not provided, probably they are not meant to be called from outside or from a derived class.

---

By the way, the MapChangedEventHandler is not an event. It's a delegate.
Events can be of that type, but their names are independant.

Like this:

```
class TestClass
{
    these are the events of the class:
    public event MapChangedEventHandler SomeEvent1;
    public event MapChangedEventHandler SomeEvent2;
    public event MapChangedEventHandler SomeEvent3;

    //now this method calls the events (events can only be raised from inside the class)
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //do lots of stuff
        if (SomeEvent1 != null) SomeEvent1(whatever arguments it takes);

        //do other stuff
        if (SomeEvent2 != null) SomeEvent2(another arguments);
    }

    //now, if you want to let derived classes to raise events...
    protected void OnSomeEvent3(Same Parameters As MapChangedEventHandler)
    {
        if (SomeEvent3 != null) SomeEvent3(parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. But according to Microsoft compiler create private event variables for events declared on classes and _The compiler also creates the two public methods add_EventName and remove_EventName. These methods are event hooks that allow delegates to be combined or removed from the event delegate eh. The details are hidden from the programmer._ As you pointed out  in your _if_  the event is called if it's not null. My doubt is who creates the EventHandler. I don't know if it's created on Add_Event hidden method.

Comment: The events always start as null delegates. The handler methods are created when you add handlers to the event: `SomeClass.SomeEvent += SomeHandler;`. Adding a handler to the event makes it not null. When removing a handler: `SomeClass.SomeEvent -= SomeHandler;`

Comment: Yes. The problem is the LayoutAwarePage class doesn't have any of these registrations for this event. Because of this I can't understand how this event until now.

Comment: I've analyzed BasicControls example and realized that I didn't pay proper attention. Specifically this example doesn't make use of MapChangedEventHandler event. In the main and XAML files there aren't any mention of binding DefaultViewModel and register of mentioned event.